# Loader not working during synchronous ajax call in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, loading, synchronous

Loader not working during a synchronous(Async:false) ajax call in google chrome. Working fine in Firefox & IE. During my debug testing, Loader showing until ajax request start. getting struck off or disappears when request sent to server, where I kept a debug point. I have tried other solutions like use of ajaxStart, beforeSend & ajax loader ect., But no use. Please give valid solution

```
 <div id="LoaderDiv" style="display: none">
    <img id="ImageLoader" src="Images/loading.gif" />
 </div>
```

---

```
            $('#LoaderDiv').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: servicePath,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.d);
                    $('#LoaderDiv').hide();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Maybe put the ajax call inside another function and use setTimeout to call it after 100 mss or something small?

Comment: It means animation of GIF stuck in between. right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906278/show-modal-loading-div-is-not-running-in-google-chrome-and-ie-browsers-firefox

Comment: @ artm: Tried but no use;

Comment: @Apul Gupta: Yes, but that will happen only when developer tools opened, if not, loader not even visible.

Comment: In sync mode, the previous call of show() maybe stuck. You should use timeout for `$('#LoaderDiv').show();`, not ajax call.

Comment: sorry I did not get your question. The gif was first showing and then after the request is sent to the server it disappeared. That is what I expect too. am I missing something?

Comment: @Degen Sharew: Thanks for ur Interest. Actually, my requirement is to show loading icon until the request returns from server during a synchronous ajax call. but it is not working in case of google chrome.

Comment: @KiranNuthanapati check my answer for long comment :-) and possible solution.

Comment: use async: true or use jquery when done method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was also facing same problem from last 1 year Even with async: false. Finally got a best solution, but not sure that it will work in you case, it worked me 101%.

Below is code:-

```
    $.ajax({ 
                .. , 
             beforeSend: function () { showLoader(); },

             success: function (data) { hideLoader(); } 
    });


function showLoader() {
    $("#progressbar").css("display", "");
}

function hideLoader() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#progressbar").css("display", "none");
    }, 1000);
}
```

you can make these two function common in any common javascript file. So that you can call these function multiple places or js files.

Html is :

```
<div class="spinnermodal" id="progressbar" style="display: none; z-index: 10001">
  <div style="position: fixed; z-index: 10001; top: 50%; left: 50%; height:65px">
      <img src="~/Images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Css is:

```
.spinnermodal {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0.5;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 100000;
    }
```

Try this. I hope it will work for you as well. Happy coding :-)

Comment: The spinner might not show as well when using async=false, so if above answer does not still show the loader, try removing this, it resolved issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

Put setTimeout before the ajax request. I have tried many solutions but this one definitely works.

```
$("#loader").show();
setTimeout(function () {
  //AJAX REQUEST CODE
  $("#loader").hide();
},10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or simply this

```
$.ajax({ 
                    .. , 
                 beforeSend: function () { $('#LoaderDiv').show(); },

                 success: function (data) { $('#LoaderDiv').hide(); } 
        });
```

which will make it little more fast

Answer (score 1):

```
Don't use async: false, Solution is this:-

var requestStatus = 1;
$('#LoaderDiv').show();
if( requestStatus != 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: servicePath,
                beforeSend: function() {
                   requestStatus = 0;
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.d);
                    $('#LoaderDiv').hide();
                    requestStatus = 1;
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in **google-chrome** it is working. May be check if you have any other error or try to post more code if you are leaving out some code on your question.

check your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvdu4dyx/), it is working.

I only added this to your code:

```
error: function(data){
                       $('#LoaderDiv').hide(); 
               }
```

---

But notice I added the **error handle function** because with out it the image ( your **gif** ) will show forever when error happens. ( If you were getting any error response from the server then this will be a solution)

Answer (score 0):

Just set little time out for your ajax call to fix loader issue:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: servicePath,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d);
            $('#LoaderDiv').hide();
        }
    });
}, 500);
```