# Show modal loading div is not running in Google Chrome and IE browsers, Firefox is ok

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, soap

I would like to show "please wait, loading" spinning circle during process SOAP call. I have a problem with show modal screen in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 9,10,11. Firefox is OK.

If i remove `$("body").removeClass("loading");` from `someMethodSOAP()`, loading screen show correct in Google Chrome and IE.

Duration of SOAP call is one second, so loading screen should be show.

I want to show loading screen in Google Chrome and IE, but i do not know how to do it? And why Firefox browser working correct and Google Chrome and IE not?

I use:
[jQuery 2.1.1][ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js ]
[jquery.soap 1.3.8][ http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/ ]
[modal window solution from:[ [How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation) ]

Thank you.

my code:

**index.php**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

<style type="text/css">
    .modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    }

    /* When the body has the loading class, we turn
       the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
    body.loading {
        overflow: hidden;   
    }

    /* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
       modal element will be visible */
    body.loading .modal {
        display: block;
    }

    div.modal div {
        position: absolute;
        top:50%;            
        left:50%;            
        width: 20%;            
        height: 10%;        
        margin:-5% 0 0 -10%;    
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<script charset="UTF-8" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script charset="UTF-8" src="jquery.soap.js"></script>

<script>
    var WEB_SERVICE_URL = 'path to SOAP';

    function someMethodSOAP(id) {
        var xml;
        $.soap({
            url: WEB_SERVICE_URL,
            method: "testMethod",
            appendMethodToURL:false,
            async: false,
            data: {
                ID: id,
            },
            beforeSend: function (SOAPEnvelope)  {
                $("body").addClass("loading");            //loading turn on
            },
            success: function (soapResponse) {            //OK
                xml = soapResponse.toString();
            },
            error: function (SOAPResponse) {            //FAULT:
                xml = SOAPResponse.toString();
            }
        });

        $("body").removeClass("loading");                //loading turn off

        return xml;
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        /*$("body").addClass("loading");
        $("body").removeClass("loading");*/

        someMetodSOAP(1);
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal"> <!-- loading-->
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif'">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
I try this code (below), but still not working.
Behavior: Method test_loading CALL method on server, which during 5 seconds. This code waiting (async:false) 5 seconds and after web browser show loading. I do not understand it. Loading is show after `someMetodSOAP(5);` is completed, but I want to show loading before `someMetodSOAP(5);`.

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {

        $("body").addClass("loading");

        someMetodSOAP(5);

        //$("body").removeClass("loading");
    });

    var WEB_SERVICE_URL = '../soap_nu.php';

    function someMetodSOAP(second) {

        var xml;
        $.soap({
            url: WEB_SERVICE_URL,
            method: "test_loading",
            appendMethodToURL:false,
            async: false,
            data: {
                parametr: second
            },
            beforeSend: function (SOAPEnvelope)  {
            },
            success: function (soapResponse) {
                xml = soapResponse.toString();
            },
            error: function (SOAPResponse) {
                xml = SOAPResponse.toString();
            }
        });

        return xml;
    }
</script>
```

**SOLVED:**
I found deffered-object from: api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ (I do not have reputation for this link, sorry.). It help me.
I hope that help you:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

<style type="text/css">
    .block {display: block !important}
    #loading {
        display: none;
        /*etc. for example css spinner*/
    }
</style>

<script charset="UTF-8" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script charset="UTF-8" src="jquery.soap.js"></script>

<script>
    var WEB_SERVICE_URL = 'path to SOAP';

    function someMethodSOAP(id){
        var d = $.Deferred();

        $.soap({
            url: WEB_SERVICE_URL,
            method: "testMethod",
            appendMethodToURL:false,
            async: true,
            data: {
                ID: id,
            },
            success: function (soapResponse) {      //SOAP OK
                try {
                    d.resolve(soapResponse.toString());
                } catch(e){
                    d.reject(SOAP_THROW);
                }
            },
            error: function (soapResponse) {        //SOAP FAULT:
                try {
                    d.reject(soapResponse.toString());
                } catch(e){
                    d.reject(SOAP_THROW);
                }
            }
        });

        return d.promise();
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        //create some promises
        var promises = new Array();
        promises.push(someMethodSOAP(1));   //only one promise

        $("#loading").addClass("block");        //start loading
        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function(xml){   //Resolve
            $("#loading").removeClass("block"); //finish loading
            /*PASS*/
        }).fail(function(xml){                          //Reject
            $("#loading").removeClass("block"); //finish loading
            /*FAIL*/
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="loading"> <!--loading-->
        <div><!-- css spinner --></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906172/loader-not-working-during-synchronous-ajax-call-in-chrome

Comment: I just created recursion :) You two can work together :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove `async: false`, then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `loading` class only after the call is completed.
Once the call is complete and a response is received it executes the success/failure function.
Try this.

```
$.soap({
        url: WEB_SERVICE_URL,
        method: "testMethod",
        appendMethodToURL:false,
        async: false,
        data: {
            ID: id,
        },
        beforeSend: function (SOAPEnvelope)  {
            $("body").addClass("loading");            //loading turn on
        },
        success: function (soapResponse) {            //OK
            xml = soapResponse.toString();
            $("body").removeClass("loading");  
        },
        error: function (SOAPResponse) {            //FAULT:
            xml = SOAPResponse.toString();
            $("body").removeClass("loading");  
        }
});
```